# Changing the contact picture placeholder on incoming calls on Android

Tags: android

I want to display different images according to the person who is calling (in case he is not on the contacts list)
For example if the person is not on the contacts list or doesn't have a picture, I want to display the flag of the country he is calling from.
Is there a way to display a custom image there?
Thanks.